# How to insert check box value in MYSQL using Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql

I have three Checkbox in HTML and I got the checkbox value in Python.If I select the Checkbox means the value should be insert as "yes" in MYSQL Database otherwise It should be insert as "No".I had tried but I don't know how to get Answer.Please help me,Thanks in Advance:)

Here is my Code:
HTML:

```
<form action='/hello' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Panchayath <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="yes" id="panchayath"><br>
     Ward  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value=" yes" id=" ward"><br>
    Results  <input type="checkbox" name="chec[]" value=" yes" id=" results">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'bucketlist'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    print("hlo")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("cat")
        panchayath = request.form.getlist('checks[]')
        print panchayath
        ward = request.form.getlist('check[]')
        print ward
        Results = request.form.getlist('chec[]')
        print Results
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # cursor.execute()
        print "yes"
        # cursor.execute("insert into try_chk3  values (%s,%s,%s)", (some_var))
        # query = "CREATE TABLE saracheck( panchayath  VARCHAR(40), ward VARCHAR(40),Results VARCHAR (40))"
        # cursor.execute(query)
        query = "INSERT INTO saracheck(panchayath,ward,Results) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
        a=cursor.execute(query, (panchayath,ward,Results))
        print a
        print "execuet"
        # cursor.execute(query,(first_name,last_name,email_id,can_pic,logo_pic))
        conn.commit()


    return render_template("form.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivDHS.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you naming the fields like "checks", "check" and "chec", it either seems like all of them would have been name = "checks[]" or it's just poor style of naming.

Also aren't you trying to get the values of all three fields? Then you should be trying to get `Results` of all three of them right?

Can you please also post what you are getting as output so far?

Comment: I am new to python ,I want to insert check box value in database if it is checked?

Comment: And I post my output page above

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label for="">Amenities Required</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="Bike" checked> I have a bike<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="Boat" > I have a boat<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="cycle"> I have a cycle<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="wagnor"> I have a wagnor<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="safari" > I have a safari<br>

      if request.method=='POST':
      amin=request.form.getlist("users")
      str1 = ','.join(amin)
      c.execute("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(%s)",[str1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <input type="checkbox" name="clinic_info" value="Clinial abnormalities">&nbsp; Clinial abnormalities 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <input type="checkbox" name="clinic_info" value="Cytological abnormalities">&nbsp; Cytological abnormalities
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <input type="checkbox" name="clinic_info" value="Low grade(L-SL)HPV"> &nbsp;Low grade(L-SL)HPV
    </div>
</div>

'''



@app.route('/index', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        clinical_info = request.form.getlist('clinic_info')
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        clinical_info = ','.join(clinical_info)
        values = (clinical_info)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (table_name) VALUES (%s)',values)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return 'You have successfully send to mysql database!'
    return render_template('clinical.html')
```